# Mysql max of counts per group

Tags: mysql, count, max

I have the following table:

```
+---------+--------+-------+
| client  | session| boat  |
+---------+--------+-------+
|       1 |   1943 |     3 |
|       1 |   1943 |     4 |
|       1 |   1944 |     3 |
|       1 |   1944 |     4 |
|       1 |   1945 |     4 |
|       2 |   1944 |     3 |
|       2 |   1944 |     4 |
|       3 |   1944 |     3 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

And i want to get the max count of boats, then I did this:

```
SELECT boat,session,max(counter) as max_boats FROM (SELECT boat,COUNT(boat) as counter,session FROM `test` GROUP BY boat,session) as cont2 GROUP BY boat
```

Result:

```
+------+---------+-----------+
| boat | session | max_boats |
+------+---------+-----------+
|    3 |    1943 |         3 |
|    4 |    1943 |         2 |
+------+---------+-----------+
```

So, my problem is this query is returning me "session = 1943" and this is wrong. As you can see in the original table, boat 3 has three rows BUT with session 1944 and boat 4 has two sessions BUT with session 1944 too.

Problem is, when I do max(counter), MySQL returns me the first session, not the row corresponding to max(counter).

Maybe my approach is wrong and entire query is wrong.

Thanks for your answers.

Solution would be:

```
+------+---------+-----------+
| boat | session | max_boats |
+------+---------+-----------+
|    3 |    1944 |         3 |
|    4 |    1944 |         2 |
+------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key on the table ?

Comment: Yeah there is a primary key, "id_test"

Comment: Actually you do not need the primary key, added an answer check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get this, which may not be the best way, you may check out other options too.

```
select 
x.boat, 
x.session, 
max_boats
from (
  select 
  boat, 
  session, 
  count(*) cnt
  from boats
  group by boat, session
)x
join(
  select boat, 
  max(cnt) max_boats
  from(
    select 
    boat, 
    session, 
    count(*) cnt
    from boats
    group by boat, session
  )y
  group by boat
)t on x.boat = t.boat and x.cnt = t.max_boats
```

Comment: Maybe not the best way, but truth is you are the only one with a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `max_boats`, `session` FROM `boats` GROUP BY `session` ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

**Output:**

```
+-----------+---------+
| max_boats | session |
+-----------+---------+
|         5 |    1944 |
|         2 |    1943 |
|         1 |    1945 |
+-----------+---------+
```

You can limit the output to the first one by using `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `max_boats`, `session` FROM `boats` GROUP BY `session` ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

**Output:**

```
+-----------+---------+
| max_boats | session |
+-----------+---------+
|         5 |    1944 |
+-----------+---------+
```

**Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59e53/3**

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add how should looks the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
SELECT COUNT(*), client, session
FROM `test` 
GROUP BY client, session
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

:)